# requests in Python not sending data to external program

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the below requests for GET & POST and the GET's work fine and the post shows a 200 response but when i check the external program it has not received any data from the post.

```
import requests
import json

class BearerAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
    def __call__(self, r):
        r.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer " + self.token
        return r
    
class BearerAuth2(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
    def __call__(self, s):
        s.headers["authorization"] = "api " + self.token
        return s
headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}
    
response = requests.get('https://api', auth=BearerAuth('123'))
response2 = requests.get('https://api2', auth=BearerAuth('123'))
splunktok = requests.post('https://http-inputs', data={response, respons2}, headers=headers, auth=BearerAuth2('456'))
print(response.json(), response2.json())
```

What i want to do is get all the response body data from response & response 2 and use it in the POST to my external program. im not sure if i need to store the response as raw in variables first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive worked this out. I added the below

after the first request i add

```
payload=response.json()
```

and then on the post i added

```
data=json.dumps(payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the `requests.Response` objects as a set:

```
data={response, respons2}
```

Assuming you intend to send the JSON responses, you can do something like:

```
data={**response.json(), **respons2.json()}
```

Comment: Hi @m01010011, This doesnt work and i get the error "TypeError: 'list' object is not a mapping"